# how to get the most recent process id of specific application

Tags: 12.04

i need to get the most recent ID of specific application. As soon as the application starts, the id should be taken. Please, help. Any idea?

Regards, 
Uguudei

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! What kind of ID are you talking about? process id? But there can be many as forks have their own for each of the childs. Please explain a bit further of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Imagine i have executed busybox microcom -s 57600 /dev/ttyUSB0 on terminal. And i get process id of busybox by using pidof busybox which gives me the PID. Unfortunately, i had executed busybox microcom -s 9600 /dev/ttyACM0. Then i get 2 PIDs. I need to distinguish them. I am coding on java and need to accomplish it.

Comment: Add these very very important details to your question, by *editing* it. This is how the site works, being a Q&A site (rather than a discussion forum).

Comment: @gertvdijk. Thx Mate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple process id (pid) in Bash scripting, you're looking for `$!`:

```
$ kcalc & # starts calculator in background
[1] 15989
$ echo $! # shows pid of last run command
15989
```

In case you want to find out the pid of a running process (example with `kwin`), try:

```
$ pidof kwin # kwin is my window manager
3504
```